# selected item ind dropdown when editing

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

i have this code right here:

```
<select name="group">
    <option value="">Choose a group....</option>
    <?php foreach($groups as $group):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $group['groupID']?>" selected="yes"><?php      echo     $group['name']?></option>

    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

my question is how would i code the 'option' tag in my dropdown so that when i edit an existing data, the selected group(admin, users, moderators) of the data i will be editing will appear when i edit it.thanks.

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: when i put selected="selected" under option tag, i get to have the dropdown options but what i want is that when for instance i chose a data which has a group that is 'User', whenever i will edit it, the dropdown option will automatically be user, in short, the dropdown option that the data has been reassigned to will be the one displayed when i will edit it.

Comment: You want to edit the user's group automaticaly when you edit the group list? Like, if a user is Admin, so when you change it to Root, the group is updated in any user with this group?

Comment: ahm, picture out this, i chose a data, with first and full name with it, along with it is what group it should belong, so i chose User among the three options User, Admin and Moderators. what i want is when i click edit, it will redirect to a page where it will display the first name, full name and the group it selected in the dropdown. in my case i did not get the group it belonged when i clicked edit, instead it display the first option in the dropdown.what will i add in my code then, i was told to put an if but im clueless.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected="yes" HTML attribute of the option tag should be only one. You need to put it on the right group.

Set a PHP variable like $selected_group that is true if the group is the right one, and print the selected attribute only for that group.
Set it to false instead.

For example, if your selected group id is putted as a request parameter called groupID you should use the code below:

```
<select name="group">
    <option value="">Choose a group....</option>
    <?php foreach($groups as $group):?>
    <?php if ($group['groupID'] == $_REQUEST['groupID']) $selected_group = true; else $selected_group = false; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $group['groupID']?>" <? if ($selected_group) echo 'selected="yes"'; ?>><?php      echo     $group['name']?></option>

    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

You could set the chosen groupid as a array member inside $groups, for example:

```
$groups[0]['selected'] = true;
```

In this case change the line inside the loop like this one:

```
<?php if ($group['selected']) $selected_group = true; else $selected_group = false; ?>
```