# Selected Value for MySQL generated Drop Down List

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I have a mysql generate dropdown list..need to add in a pre selected option such as "Please Choose Availability".  Not too sure how to do this as the drop down content is generated from a database

```
<?php


$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT availability FROM properties";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='property'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='". $row['availability']. "'>" . $row['availability'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: what is the problem? you dont get values in dropdown?

Comment: It seems this is a duplicate query:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848079/selected-item-ind-dropdown-when-editing

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<select name='property'><option value=''>Please Choose Availability</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want static first value for dropdown then you can do it like this.

```
echo "<select name='property'><option value=''>Please Choose Availability </option>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<option value='". $row['availability']. "'>" . $row['availability'] ."</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";
```