# populate a drop down from a table and then set the selected option from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of order statuses that a sales order can have; the statuses are not necessarily sequential. I can get these statuses into a drop down using the following:

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM `mjj_order_status` ORDER BY Order_status_name DESC';
$result_order_status = mysql_query($sql1);

echo '<select name="Order_status">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_order_status)) {
    echo '<option
    value="'.$row['Order_status_ID'].'">'.$row['Order_status_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

My problem occurs when I try to fetch the order data from the DB, and then set the dropdown list to that order's status. I can run the query to get the order status that should be selected, but am not sure how to code how to apply this information. The query to get the order status ID is:

```
SELECT Order_status FROM `mjj_orders` WHERE Order_ID = $_POST['Order_ID']
```

I have searched (I think comprehensively) and I haven't found a feasible answer or - to be fair - one that I can understand.

(I have found a question similar to this one, but I am unsure how to get them to elaborate... [selected item ind dropdown when editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848079/selected-item-ind-dropdown-when-editing)).

Any and all advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the variable that contains the current order status?

Comment: @Dave Um, that's my problem, I don't know how to get that variable set, and then applied to only the correct order status.

Comment: Do you have a different table that contains the customer orders with their status?

Comment: Yup, one where the orders exist with a status, and one which lists the possible statuses.

Comment: if you need specific variables in the response, you will have to show the code where you retrieve the order they are inquiring about from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just drop in some logic checking what status the order you are working on has.

```
$sql = "SELECT Order_status FROM 'mjj_orders' WHERE Order_ID = ".$_POST['Order_ID']; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$myorder=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM `mjj_order_status` ORDER BY Order_status_name DESC'; 
$result_order_status = mysql_query($sql1); 

echo '<select name="Order_status">'; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_order_status)) { 
    if($myorder['Order_status']==$row['Order_status_ID']){
        $selectCurrent=' selected';
    }else{
        $selectCurrent='';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$row['Order_status_ID'].'" '.$selectCurrent.'>'.$row['Order_status_name'].'</option>';
} 
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: this assumes `$myorder` is an array containing information about the order that the person is inquiring about

Comment: Cool, how do I set the `$myorder['status'] part?`

Comment: um...  your questions stated `My problem occurs when I try to fetch the order data from the DB...`   how are you doing that.

Comment: I use this query `SELECT Order_status FROM 'mjj_orders' WHERE Order_ID = "'.$order_no.'"';` which I have test and it works...

Answer (score 0):

just mark the option where order_status_id = the id that should be selected with `selected`. eg. the option that will be selected will look like `<option selected value="...` like this:

```
$id_to_select = // Your logic to get the id to select

$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM `mjj_order_status` ORDER BY Order_status_name DESC';
$result_order_status = mysql_query($sql1);

echo '<select name="Order_status">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_order_status)) {
  if($id_to_select == $row['Order_status_ID'])
    echo '<option selected value="'.$row['Order_status_ID'].'">'.$row['Order_status_name'].'</option>';
  else     
    echo '<option value="'.$row['Order_status_ID'].'">'.$row['Order_status_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Thanks Erik. The real problem here is how to do just what you mentioned.

Comment: @tithij ... does this explain it now ?

Comment: Thanks Erik. Did just that, with the query to select the correct order status ID. Tested the query, it is correct. But I still get the list of statuses in their stored order with the first one selected. (I also tried removing the `ORDER BY` part of the `$sql1` query)

Comment: make sure that the `$id_to_select` variable has a value that matches an `order_status_id`

Comment: Okay, that seems to be the problem, it isn't returning a number. Getting a **Resource id #7** error.

Comment: try with `"SELECT Order_status FROM mjj_orders WHERE Order_ID = '" . $_POST['Order_ID'] . "'"`

Comment: Quick question: where does that query get executed to return a value?

Comment: I still get the **Resource id #7** error. Am investigating further